# testing performance on Linux dockers

Tags: jmeter, load, perfmon

I have several scripts testing performance of Linux server. there are about 12 dockers containers running inside the Linux.

We are interested on collecting also metrics of containers (right now we are collecting only of the Linux machine itself)
Is there any plugin for this? or can this be done with the Perfmon plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of monitoring Docker instance statistics:

1. [Built-in Runtime Metrics](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/)
2. [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) - probably this one will be the easiest to setup and use
3. Any of [built-in Linux monitoring tools](https://blog.serverdensity.com/80-linux-monitoring-tools-know/)

Of course you can normally use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) as this way you will get performance monitoring results integrated into your test script and be able to correlate JMeter metrics with server health metrics. Just make sure there is a TCP/UDP connectivity between JMeter and [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md), default port is 4445 so make sure container [exposes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) this port to the outside world.